# Average Partial Effects from model.avg() GAMMs

Tags: r, mixed-models, gam

I used the `MuMIn::model.avg()` function to generate a set of top models which represented 95% of the weight of all models considered. Using this model average object, I also generated predictions from my top models.

Say my top 3 models are as follows:

```
catch ~ s(effort) + s(year) + s(month) + s(open_water) + s(pop_dens)
catch ~ s(effort) + s(year) + s(month) + s(forest)
catch ~ s(effort) + s(year) + s(month) + s(open_water)
```

where open water/forest are proportions.

I would like to see what the average partial effects of open water is in a plot, but it shows up in two of my top models and each has a different weight associated with it. Is there a straightforward way to assess this?

The current approach I am taking is generating estimates from each model, multiplying by the weight of that model, then adding the estimates from the models to get an averaged estimate across the set of models.

ex code:

```
# get models with variable of interest
water_mods <- top_mod_list[grep(pattern = "water", x = names(top_mod_list))]
# get normalized weights
water_weights <-  model.sel(water_mods) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(mod = rownames(.))

# use mean values of all other predictors, only change variable of interest
pdat <- means %>% select(-water)
pdat$water <- seq(min(landing_dat$water),
                  max(landing_dat$water),
                  length.out = 200)

# predict response based on changes to variable of interest
water_predict <- 
  map(water_mods,
      ~pdat %>% 
        mutate(pred = predict(.x,
                              newdata = pdat, 
                              # type = "response",
                              newdata.guaranteed = TRUE,
               weighted_pred = pred * water_weights$weight)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to see the average function? The estimated functions **mean** two different things in the models this smooth occurs. In neither model is the term `s(open_water)`

> the *effect of `open water` on the response*.

It is the

> the *effect of `open water` on the response* **given** (conditional upon) the other terms in the model

And as you have different terms in the models the term `s(open_water)` means different things which are likely incompatible; it is very likely you would be averaging an apple and an orange, not two apples.

Rather than this AIC, multimodel averaging approach, I would approach the model estimation problem here by adding extra shrinkage penalties to all or a subset of terms. The former is done by adding `select = TRUE` to your call:

```r
m <- gam(catch ~ s(effort) + s(year) + s(month) + s(open_water) + s(pop_dens) + s(forest),
  data = foo,
  method = "REML",
  select = TRUE,
  family = something)
```

Which will never result in the effect of one or more of the smooths being **exactly** 0 but they could get shrunk towards 0 and may have effectively 0 (but not exactly 0) effect on the response.

Comment: I am unable to take the approach you've suggested due to concurvity between habitat variables, that's why they were isolated when modeled rather than included in the same model structure. I am using model averaged predictions to create a map of predicted fish catch throughout the study area. Since I am using the model averaged predictions for that purpose, I thought there may be a way to also average the partial effects given the set of models that I averaged for the spatial predictions as well.